# Check lines and merge cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if there are lines with same id and if exist then merge this cells. I tried to insert the data into a pivot table, but it not works, I need to do manually. Any ideea how i can do this? Is there an option other than vba?
Thanks!

My table looks like this one:

```
Group  Status  Id  Date
       Log In   1   01/01/2019
       Log Out  1   02/01/2019
       Log In   2   01/01/2019
       Log Out  2   02/01/2019
       Log Out  2   03/01/2019
       Log Out  2   04/01/2019
A               1  
B               2
```

The table should look like this:

```
Group  Status  Id  Date
  A    Log In   1   01/01/2019
  A    Log Out  1   02/01/2019
  B    Log In   2   01/01/2019
  B    Log Out  2   02/01/2019
  B    Log Out  2   03/01/2019
  B    Log Out  2   04/01/2019
```

Comment: What do you mean with merge cells? Cause the way you have formatted your question now it can be done with a simple formula.

Comment: for example the last to rows from table need to be compared with the rest of the table and if the id is the same then insert the value from column a

Answer (score 0):

Under **Group** write the folowing `=IF(C2=$C$8,$A$8,IF(C2=$C$9,$A$9,"")`
This formula uses the `IF` function to compare the **Id** field with the refernce two rows

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that if insert the formula multiple times the range changes too. I mean, if I insert the formula om row 3 i have =IF(C3=$C9,$A9,IF(C3=$C10,$A10,""). Instead of $C8,$A8 .. i have $C9

Comment: I fixed the solution, the `$` sign in front of row / column fixes the reference so it will not change while draging or copy passting

Comment: Hi! There is still a problem.It works only if the second if is equal with the seached group. If i have 100 lines and the search item is on line 88 the function will not return the value. However, if the second "if" is equal 88 it will return the searched value

Comment: I tried to do with something like this, but is not wrorking. =IF(C2=(C7:C12);(A7:A12);IF(C2=(C7:C12);(A7:A12);"")) It is possible to define a range insted of a single value? Thanks

Comment: You shouldnt use a range below your data. Put your reference table `A               1  
B               2  ` in another range like `H2:I3`